# What to do with 3rd party Javadoc

Tags: java, version-control, javadoc

Looking to see what others do with 3rd party (vendor) java documents?  Do they get placed under source control so everyone can have access to them?  Placed out on a local shared directory? other solutions that people have to work well.

We use clearcase and have developers spread out through the US along with a couple of off shore groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have some kind of intra/extranet available, I recommend collecting all of them there in one place. If you don't intend to modify them, I don't see any benefit in keeping them under version control.

Answer (score 2):

I add them to source control.

I have

- lib/ for 3rd party jar files
- lib-doc/ for 3rd party javadocs
- lib-src/ for 3rd party sources

I find this good for future reference, when I may need to find the source or docs for the specific version of the api that I use. It could be that in 6 months or 12 months time, the version I use is no longer publicly available.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)

With its Bugtracker and its Wiki it is easy to manage documents that you need for your project. In addition you have a lot of useful plugins for that tool. We do not put this type of documents in our version control cause it makes our projects to big after a while.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the word 'document', I suppose you are talking about javadocs?

Projects that use Maven have it take care of such things.

For other projects, it is possible to **have the external javadocs shared by**:

- accessible on the **web** (just configure your environment to display them) : that's easy to set up, easy on resources, maybe be slow (or down) from time to time...
- accessible on a **common file system** : that is not always possible or practical (think about your offshore groups)
- committed in source control (possibly in a different place, so that common synchronizing tasks don't have to check them) : easy also ; might be a performance problem in some configurations